# ExpressionEngine textarea not supporting embedded code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expressionengine

I have installed the ExpressionEngine 2.11.  and I have created a Channel Field of a textarea type to post the full description of my articles.

My issue comes when trying to include Twitter or Instagram embed code like this one

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-cards="hidden" data-lang="es"><p lang="es" dir="ltr"> SÚPER QUINIELA <a href="//twitter.com/hashtag/NFL?src=hash">#NFL</a> <br><br>¡Gana tarjetas de regalo y viajes a partidos oficiales!<br><br>Juega  <a href="t.co/SVMJMjRaHZ">t.co/SVMJMjRaHZ</a> <a href="t.co/MIkMkRdCAa">pic.twitter.com/MIkMkRdCAa</a></p>&mdash; Innovasport (@innovasport) <a href="twitter.com/innovasport/status/771460908413440000">1 de septiembre de 2016</a></blockquote>
<script async src="platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I've got the following error

[image: ExpressionEngine TextArea eror]

Any idea how to let textarea fields to support embeddeds HTML characters?

Greetings, Leo

Comment: What is the characterset for the column field_id_29?

Comment: Encoding: utf8
Collation: utf8_general_ci